# Deny access to URI

Tags: apache, .htaccess, setenvif

I'm trying to deny access to a certain uri, namely `/admin/` and have tried this .htaccess file:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI !^/admin/ not_admin_uri

Order deny,allow
Deny from all
allow from 356.244.33.
allow from env=not_admin_uri
```

This works for the example IP range, but not for the "not_admin_uri" part.

What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To negate a match you cannot place `!` in the `SetEnvIf` directive. You need to use **negative lookahead** like this:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/(?!admin/) not_admin_uri
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using a rewrite rule. If not from your IP then block access.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.123\.123\.
RewriteRule ^admin/? - [F,L]
```