# 403 forbidden response still sends body

Tags: apache, .htaccess, setenvif

I set up my `.htaccess` file so that only certain IP ranges can access the `/admin` portion of my site, as asked in this question: [Deny access to URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014348/deny-access-to-uri)

That works... in testing. When I tried this on my live, https enabled, site something strange happened:

When I GET the `/admin` page, I receive a **403 Forbidden** status code **but** I also get the body as if nothing happened.

How is that possible, and how do I fix it?

Here's the eventual .htaccess:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^(?!/admin) not_admin_uri

Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
allow from 366.241.93.
allow from env=not_admin_uri
```

Also: if I remove the last `allow` rule it actually does block the request (though it then, of course, blocks all reguest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The document for the `403` status code (which was `403.shtml`) did not exist, in which case Apache apparently just executes the request.